# Why is pandas.melt messing with my dtypes?

Tags: pandas

I have some pivot code that is failing with the error

> pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

I have tracked down the problem to a previous call to [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

Here are the dtypes before the melt:

```python
frame.dtypes
```

```
user_id                           Int64
feature                          object
seconds_since_start_assigned      Int32
total                           float32
programme_ids                    object
q1                                Int32
q2                                Int32
q3                                Int32
q4                                Int32
q5                                Int32
q6                                Int32
q7                                Int32
q8                                Int32
q9                                Int32
week                              Int32
```

Now for the melt

```python
frame1 = pd.melt(
     frame,
     id_vars=['user_id', 'week'],
     value_vars=['q1', 'q2', 'q3', 'q4', 'q5', 'q6', 'q7', 'q8', 'q9'],
     var_name='question',
     value_name='score')
frame1.dtypes
```

```
user_id     object
week        object
question    object
score       object
```

Why has the call to `melt` replaced the `Int32` I need for `score` with `object`?

Comment: Have a look at pivot_longer from pyjanitor and see if the names_ transform parameter is helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the nullable Integer data type (capital 'I' in 'Int32'). This is still a fairly new data type and so not all of the functionality is there. Namely there's a [big warning under the Construction section](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html#construction), and the issue is that Series **cannot** infer a nullable integer dtype, though perhaps someday:

> In the future, we may provide an option for Series to infer a nullable-integer dtype.

We can see this ourselves. Series will not infer the correct type and are left with `object` as the only container that can hold the nullable Interger missing. Arrays work though.

```
import pandas as pd
arr = [1, pd._libs.missing.NAType(), 4]

pd.Series(arr)
#0       1
#1    <NA>
#2       4
#dtype: object   #  <- Did not infer the type :(

pd.array(arr)
#<IntegerArray>
#[1, <NA>, 4]
#Length: 3, dtype: Int64
```

So you melt, get a Series and pandas cannot infer the dtype so it gets cast to `object` after the melt. For now, you'll have to explicitly convert back to 'Int32'.