# Pandas operation stack() drops Categorical type from MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, stack, multi-index, categorical-data

I have a pandas DataFrame whose rows and columns have a Categorical MultiIndex.
However, the stack() operation, which moves indices from columns to rows, strips the Categorical type, i.e., it creates a new index with a string.

Why is it doing this?  Is there anyway to stop it?  I am looking for a solution that doesn't require manually resetting the Categorical type after each operation.

Note, others found similar problems with melt() stripping the Categorical type
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64900604/categorical-column-after-melt-in-pandas,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63138258/why-is-pandas-melt-messing-with-my-dtypes]

### Code

The code below illustrates the problem.  I print out the type of each level of the index before and after stack() operations.  Stack seems to preserve the Categorical type of the first level, but strip the Categorical type of later levels.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# -----------------------------------
# dtype for each level of row index or column index
def get_Index_level_dtypes(df, axis):
    I = df.index if axis==0 else df.columns
    return [I.get_level_values(i).dtype for i in range(I.nlevels)]

# Print:
# (i)   name of DataFrame (or Series)
# (ii)  dtype of levels for axis = 0
# (iii) dtype of levels for axis = 1  (if not Series)
def print_Index_level_dtypes(df, S):
    print('-'*100,"\n", S, " = \n", df, "\n")  # print df name
    for i in range(2 if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame) else 1):
        print("Level data type, axis = ",i,":")
        for q in get_Index_level_dtypes(df, axis=i):
            print(q)
# -----------------------------------
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(
    [
    pd.Categorical(['A1','A1','A2','A2']),
    pd.Categorical(['B1','B2','B1','B2']),
    pd.Categorical(['C1','C1','C1','C1']),
    ])
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randn(2, 4), 
    columns=midx,
    index = pd.Categorical(['Row1','Row2'])
)
# --------------------------------------
print_Index_level_dtypes(df,"Orig")
#
# • Stack one level:
#    row index: Keeps categorical type
#    col index: strips categorical type (types are "object", ie string)
print_Index_level_dtypes(df.stack(level = [0]), "Stack_level_0")   # same behavior for all level=[i]
#
# • Stack multiple levels:
#    row index: Keeps 1st categorical type, strips rest
#    col index: strips categorical type (types are "object", ie string)
print_Index_level_dtypes(df.stack(level = [0, 1]),    "Stack_level_01")
print_Index_level_dtypes(df.stack(level = [0, 1, 2]), "Stack_level_012")
```

### Output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 Orig  = 
             A1                  A2          
            B1        B2        B1        B2
            C1        C1        C1        C1
Row1  1.764052  0.400157  0.978738  2.240893
Row2  1.867558 -0.977278  0.950088 -0.151357 

Level data type, axis =  0 :
category
Level data type, axis =  1 :
category
category
category
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 Stack_level_0  = 
                B1        B2
               C1        C1
Row1 A1  1.764052  0.400157
     A2  0.978738  2.240893
Row2 A1  1.867558 -0.977278
     A2  0.950088 -0.151357 

Level data type, axis =  0 :
category
category
Level data type, axis =  1 :
object
object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 Stack_level_01  = 
                   C1
Row1 A1 B1  1.764052
        B2  0.400157
     A2 B1  0.978738
        B2  2.240893
Row2 A1 B1  1.867558
        B2 -0.977278
     A2 B1  0.950088
        B2 -0.151357 

Level data type, axis =  0 :
category
category
object
Level data type, axis =  1 :
object
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
 Stack_level_012  = 
 Row1  A1  B1  C1    1.764052
          B2  C1    0.400157
      A2  B1  C1    0.978738
          B2  C1    2.240893
Row2  A1  B1  C1    1.867558
          B2  C1   -0.977278
      A2  B1  C1    0.950088
          B2  C1   -0.151357
dtype: float64 

Level data type, axis =  0 :
category
category
object
object
```

Comment: I dont think it is possible to maintain the categorical data types. it might be that this is because numpy does not recognize categorical data types and converts it to an object dtype. That's my opinion. You probably have to spend time with the source code to see what's going on. I had a look at pandas' melt, and cant see any special 'protection' for dtypes that numpy is not aware of.